# Ping time to remote server from Meteor Client

Tags: meteor, ping, atmosphere.js

I'm new to Meteor and wondering if anyone can point me to a package or technique for returning a ping round trip time to a remote server from a Meteor Client?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck at [SoftwareRecs.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean to cause trouble :(

Comment: It's fine, we all made the mistake at one point! Make sure to give a read to the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Would [leitwarte:ping](https://atmospherejs.com/leitwarte/ping) do the job for you?

Comment: Please do not answer blatantly off-topic questions. Here, this question asks for an external resource and will be closed as such. Answering such questions makes it look like it's okay to ask them.